# Fastest way to template and append elements from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using jQuery and Javascript, I am building a chatbox from an array of messages. My current setup is something similar to this:

HTML:

```
<div id="messageTemplate">
  <div class="messageContainer">
    <div class="chatMessage"></div>
    <div class="chatTime"></div>
    <div class="chatActions">
      <span class="chatAction deleteMessage">Delete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var template=$('#messageTemplate');
var chatbox=$('#chatbox');

$.each(messageArr,function(index,messageObject) {
  var newMessage=$(template.html()); //Make a new DOM
  newMessage.find('div.chatMessage').text(messageObject.message);
  newMessage.find('div.chatTime').text(messageObject.time);
  newMessage.find('div.chatAction.deleteMessage').click(function() {
  //Delete message Code
});  
  //Append newMessage to chatbox
  newMessage.appendTo(chatbox);
});
```

This code works, but after reading [this article](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly) I found out this is not efficient at all. With 100+ chat messages this starts to slow down.

What's the best way to be doing this? Not looking for code to be written for me, but just a general guide on the best method to template, build the html, append, and add click handlers?

Comment: If the code works this kind of questions fits better at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: How does messageArr get updated?  AJAX?  Page load?

Comment: _"I found out this is not efficient at all"_ What is the current benchmark for the procedure? If efficiency is the requirement why is jQuery being used?

Comment: This question runs the risk of getting answers based on people's opinion on which way is the best way to create new elements.  If you have a question about a problem, ask that instead.